# How to use below HTTP request to get data from server

Tags: angular

[image]I am new to angular I was given HTTP get service url to get the data from server 
How can I subscribe it and get the data.

```
/dashboard/graphics-chart/v1/{roleId}.
```

below is the method i have written in service file

```
  getgraphdata(defaultroleID): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.get(WebServiceUrl.dashboard.getPiechartData + '/' + defaultroleID)
      .pipe(map(data => data));
  }
```

How can I subscibe it in TS file.

Comment: is this method compiling with no error?

Comment: There is an error.

Comment: if the above apiService is not a HttpClient use a HttpClient to do http calls. my advice take a look at angular httpclient: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: We have a separate file where all HTTP calls are written we are just importing the same file in the above case all the https calls are written in apiservice instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your service in component constructor and call your servis method as following:

```
this.yourServiceName.getgraphdata(this.defaultroleID).subscribe(res=>{
   console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: Hi this is my service url /dashboard/graphics-chart/v1/{roleId}.

There is a error in my above mentioned code can you please check in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to it as you would to any other `Observable`. To obtain parameters from the current URL, subscribe to `paramMap` of the `ActivatedRoute`. The following component makes your HTTP request whenever the role ID changes.

Component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private dashservice: DashService, 
    private _route: ActivatedRoute ) { }
}

ngOnInit() {
  // get role ID from activated route
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
    (params: ParamMap) => { this.getchartdata(params.get('roleId')); }
  );
}

// use roleId 'default' if no parameters are passed
private getchartdata(roleId = 'default') {
  this.dashservice.getgraphdata(roleId).subscribe(
    response => {
      // handle response
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}
```

Also seeing that you don't transform your data in the HTTP call, you could remove `.map` and return the HTTP response directly.

```
getgraphdata(defaultroleID): Observable<any> {
  return this.apiService.get(WebServiceUrl.dashboard.getPiechartData + '/' + defaultroleID);
}
```

Comment: Hi this is my service url /dashboard/graphics-chart/v1/{roleId}. There is a error in my above mentioned code can you please check in to it

Comment: Does `WebServiceUrl.dashboard.getPiechartData` return the correct URL? Does it point to your URL `/dashboard/graphics-chart/v1'?

Comment: Then what error are you receiving? Can you please post the error?

Comment: You declare `defaultroleID` but aren't initializing it. I think you meant to pass it as an arugment. In that case, do `getChartData(defaultroleID: any)`. If not, do `let defaultroleID = <valid ID>;`

Comment: If you'd like to get the `roleId` from the URL, use `ActivatedRoute`. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe in the following way in your component and to read the roleId, you can inject the route.

```
constructor(
    private yourService: YourService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
) { }

yourFunction() {
    let roleId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('roleId');
    this.yourService.getgraphdata(roleId )
      .subscribe(result => ...do something with result);
}
```

Comment: How about type roleID which was given in my service.

Comment: @rohitsiriga updated, you need to inject the ActivatedRoute and then read the value roleId

Comment: @Ram Did it help you?