# How to get data from below http request

Tags: angular

How to get data from below HTTP request.

srp/dashboard/graphics-chart/v1/{roleId}.

In webservice.url.ts I decalred a variable ang assigned the URL to it.

dashboardbardata : 'srp/dashboard/graphics-chart/v1/'.

there is already get req done  below is code and file name is apiservice.ts

```
 get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { params })
  .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
```

}

How to use the above HTTP request in my service file and how to subscribe it in TS file.

Comment: You asked a similar question a couple of hours back: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60374366/6513921. How is this any different? Also please reformat the question. Your primary question is still unclear.

Comment: Yeah but there is an error in the above question so I have asked another one.
sorry if I have offended you.

Comment: **there is an error** - could you please elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use below HTTP request to get data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374366/how-to-use-below-http-request-to-get-data-from-server)

Answer (score 1):

in service `webservice.url.ts`

```
 public getData(roleId) {
    return this.apiService.get(roleId);
  }
```

in dashboard

```
 service.getData(roleId).subscribe((res: any) {
// your code

});
```